# Error GraphQL "The type of Query.GetUser must be Output Type but got: undefined."

Tags: node.js, graphql, express-graphql

Writing my First Graphql and came across this problem.

Data is not showing

**index.js**:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const graphql = require('graphql')
const {graphqlHTTP} = require('express-graphql')
const { GetUser , mutation } = require('./schema')
const { DataType } = require('./DataType')
app.use(express.json())

const schema = new graphql.GraphQLSchema({
    query: new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
        name:"Query",
        type:new graphql.GraphQLList(DataType),
        fields:{GetUser}
    }),
    mutation:new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
        name:"Mutation",
        fields:{mutation}
    })
})
app.use('/graphql',graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql:true
}))

app.listen(1200,()=>{
    console.log("SERVER AT 1200");
})
```

**schema.js**:

```
const graphql = require('graphql')
const {GraphQLObjectType , GraphQLString} = graphql
const {DataType} = require('./DataType')

var data = [
    {
        "name":"Book1",
        "price":123
    },
    {
        "name":"Book2",
        "price":1232
    },
    {
        "name":"Book3",
        "price":2021
    },
]

exports.GetUser = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name:"GetAllUser",
    type:new graphql.GraphQLList(DataType),
    fileds:{
        getAllUser:{
            name:"getUser",
            type:new graphql.GraphQLList(DataType),
            resolve:()=>{
                return data;
            }
        }
    }
})

exports.mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name:"AddData",
    fields:{
        adduser:{
            name:"adduser",
            type:data,
            args:{
                name:{type:GraphQLString},
                price:{type:graphql.GraphQLInt}
            },
            resolve:(_,args)=>{
                data.push(args)
                return args
            }
        }
    }
})
```

***DataType.js***:

```
const graphql = require('graphql')

exports.DataType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
    name:"DataType",
    fields:()=>({
        name:{
            type: graphql.GraphQLString
        },
        price:{
            type:graphql.GraphQLInt
        }
    })
})
```

Running graphql:

```
query{
  GetUser{
    name

  }
}
```

Error i get :

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The type of Query.GetUser must be Output Type but got: undefined."
    },
    {
      "message": "The type of Mutation.mutation must be Output Type but got: undefined."
    }
  ]
}
```

Error says The type of Query.GetUser must be Output Type but got: undefined.

I defined the type of the query again but still shows same error same for mutation .

Also this was my first day of Graphql .

Comment: and url of the tutorial you're following is ... ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dr2dDWzThK8&t=658s